# Periodicity of solution to initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE $$\begin{cases}
x''(t)+x(t)+x(t)^3=0\\
(x(0),x'(0))=(x_0,0)\\
\end{cases}$$ where $x(t)$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}$ ,Prove that for all $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ ,the solution of the above system is periodic.
It's a question of S.-T.Yau College Student Mathematics Contest in 2020.
I assume $p=x'(t)$ , and  get the equation $$\frac{dp}{dx}p+x+x^3=0$$ Then know $$2p^2+2x^2+x^4=2x_0^2+x_0^4$$ It's too complicated to solve this equation, and I don't know what to do afterward. How to get periodicity without solving the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to solve. Note that
$$2p^2+2x^2+x^4=2x_0^2+x_0^4$$
is a closed curve and hence $(x,p)$ is periodic.